# CodeIgniter extend user's session expiration time

Tags: codeigniter, session, cookies

Is it possible to extend user's session expiration time in CI. What I want to do is, by default every user's session cookie lasts for example 1 day, but every time user visits the site his session expiration time is extended by one more day.

I don't know if it is a good idea to do this, maybe I should just set cookies life time for like a week and that's it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe what you want is actually the default behavior.
Take a look at sess_read() and sess_update() in /system/libraries/Session.php

last_activity for an active session is updated every five minutes.

Session expiration is checked with last_activity + sess_expiration < now

So, for the behavior you want, just set your sess_expiration time to 86400 (one day), and you should be all set.

Comment: You should be setting it in the config.php file not in the actual library file. When you upgrade the codeigniter core you will lose the changes.

Comment: For the record, I meant take a look at the system file to see how Codeigniter's sessions work as relates to the original question, not to make any changes there, but I can see how that may have been unclear.

Answer (score 5):

From the [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html):

> **$sess_expiration**: The number of seconds you would like the session to last. The default value is 2 hours (7200 seconds). If you would like a non-expiring session set the value to zero: 0

Hopefully this is what you're wanting to do?

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about the Session component in CodeIgniter? You can go to config.php and set `$sess_expiration = 7200;` (7200 is the default)

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: The way I understand $sess_expiration just tells how long session cookie lives since it was created, 2 hours in this case, what I want to achieve is if user is active, his session cookie theoretically does not expire. I hope this makes more clear...

Answer (score 2):

Default session time in codeigniter is

```
$sess_expiration = 7200; // This is 2 hours
```

Also you can set `$sess_expiration = 0;` This means you are setting session for forever.

Actually I could see in codeigniter library  Session.php

```
// Set the session length. If the session expiration is
// set to zero we'll set the expiration two years from now.
if ($this->sess_expiration == 0)
{
     $this->sess_expiration = (60*60*24*365*2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$this->config->set_item('sess_expiration', $sec);
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->session = new CI_Session();
// where $sec is the seconds until expiration
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Application->config.php`

[image: here]

**For one day: 86400**
**For week   : 604800**